# Add JPEG encoder/decoder support to installed OpenJDK

Tags: java, jpeg, javax.imageio, openjdk-12

I'm trying to scale a JPEG image and save it back using the following code, however, the resulting `storage/test/thumbnail.jpg` file is just an empty file. I checked the same code with `PNG` format and it works perfectly. However, for my use case I need a JPG image and not PNG.

```
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import java.io.File
import javax.imageio.ImageIO

fun main() {
    val file = File("storage/test/original.jpg")
    val image = ImageIO.read(file.inputStream())
    val thumbnail = thumbnailOf(image)
    val thumbnailFile = File("storage/test/thumbnail.jpg")
    thumbnailFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
    thumbnailFile.outputStream().use { output ->
        ImageIO.write(thumbnail, "JPEG", output)
    }
}

fun thumbnailOf(image: BufferedImage): BufferedImage {
    val width = image.width
    val height = image.height
    val ratio = width / height.toDouble()

    if (ratio == 0.0) {
        error("Cannot determine ratio for ($width*$height)")
    }

    val newWidth = 600
    val newHeight = (newWidth / ratio).toInt()
    val scaledImage = BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)
    val at = AffineTransform()
    at.scale(newWidth / width.toDouble(), newHeight / height.toDouble())
    val ato = AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC)

    return ato.filter(image, scaledImage)
}
```

The best thing I was able to find so far is this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16026254/4112200 , which states that OpenJDK doesn't have a JPEG encoder. So, if that's the case, how can I add the JPEG encoder (or decoder) to my currently installed OpenJDK?

My currently installed OpenJDK

```
openjdk version "12" 2019-03-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12+33)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12+33, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright, here's how I have solved this.

For my case, the issue didn't have anything to do with JPEG support. JPEG is already supported, however, there were some bugs in my code in addition I used a different approach to scale the image.

1. The first bug is in this line:

```
val scaledImage = BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)
```

`ImageIO.write` cannot find an `ImageWriter` that matches with `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` and `JPG` / `JPEG`. So, I changed it to `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB`.

2. Fixing this causes an exception to be thrown at `ato.filter(image, scaledImage)`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.image.ImagingOpException: Unable to transform src image
```

I don't know what's the reason for that exception and how to fix it, but using a `Graphics2D` object to scale and render the image worked for me.

3. Even though a valid image file is generated, but it only contained black background. And that's because the supplied values of `scale()` were inconsistent.

The following is the final code where this works successfully, and how points 2 and 3 were fixed.

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import java.io.File
import javax.imageio.ImageIO

fun main() {
    val file = File("storage/test/original.jpg")
    val image = ImageIO.read(file.inputStream())
    val thumbnail = thumbnailOf(image)
    val thumbnailFile = File("storage/test/thumbnail.jpg")
    thumbnailFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
    thumbnailFile.outputStream().use { output ->
        ImageIO.write(thumbnail, "JPEG", output)
    }
}

fun thumbnailOf(image: BufferedImage): BufferedImage {
    val width = image.width
    val height = image.height
    val ratio = width / height.toDouble()

    if (ratio == 0.0) {
        error("Cannot determine ratio for ($width*$height)")
    }

    val newWidth = 600
    val newHeight = (newWidth / ratio).toInt()
    val scale = newWidth / width.toDouble()

    val scaledImage = BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)

    val graph = scaledImage.graphics as Graphics2D
    // graph.scale((newWidth / width).toDouble(), (newHeight / height).toDouble())
    graph.scale(scale, scale)

    // everything drawn with graph from now on will get scaled.
    graph.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null)
    graph.dispose()

    return scaledImage
}
```